# How to include header file in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, c++

I have a base class,A, (in C++) and want to have another class, B, that inherits class A.

```
class A{
public:
int n;
A(){n=0;}
void Test(int m);
};


class B:public A{
public:
int func();
};
```

I have A.cpp and B.cpp, separately. but When I compile B.cpp in cygwin, an error pops up saying that "undefined reference to " the function belongs to A. So I'm wondering how I can define #include"A.h" in cygwin?

Comment: Have you tried?  You made no mention of having a header file.

Comment: I tried: g++  -L/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Win7 A.h B.cpp

Comment: But it says undefined reference to the function B inherits from A.

Comment: The command that includes the header file didn't include the other .cpp file.  I am going to guess based on your reputation at `Stackoverflow` the reason your asking us this question is because you can't ask it there.  You need to do some more research on how classes work.

Comment: cygwin is nothing to do with classes or C++. Also, the reputation in a forum does not indicate ones programming skills, thus don't guess, be certain about what you say.

Comment: As the question title shows the problem is how to include .h (header file) in cygwin.

Comment: You have two heavily downvoted questions on Stackoverflow and your asking a question on how to compile code.  Neither of your files includes the header file

Comment: first my down-voted is no body's business. I ask a simple questions to learn the things. Second, the codes in the box are only for illustration, and my code includes the headers, but "again" the question is how to include them in "Cygwin". I DO NOT KNOW how to include in cygwin and that's why I asked such question.

Comment: You are right.  Trying to understand why your asking a programming question on Superuser instead of Stackoverflow.  I apologize.  There is no difference, you include header files, the exact same way. *Your example code is confusing*

Answer (score 2):

**Include Path**

To add include paths use the `-I` flag.

```
g++ -I/include/path/here -I/another/include/path -o program source.cpp
```

To view the include file search while it happens during the compilation, use the `-v` (verbose) flag.

```
g++ -v -o program source.cpp
```

---

**Library Path**

To add library paths use the `-L` flag.

```
g++ -L/lib/path/here -L/another/lib/path -o program source.cpp
```

---

**"I tried: `g++ -L/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Win7 A.h B.cpp`"**

Try:

g++ -o program A.cpp B.cpp

---

**I'm wondering how I can define #include"A.h" in cygwin?"**

This has nothing to do with cygwin. It is basic C++ knowledge. Please read [8.9 — Class code and header files](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also, directly include the header file by defining its relative path. For example to include json.h you can include it as:

**#include "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/include/json/json.h"** same as we include
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

**But make sure the package is installed**